# Java - intellij vs command prompt

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
        System.out.println("log n \tn \tn log n\tn^2 \tn^3");
    for (long i = 2; i <= 2048; i *= 2) {
        System.out.print((int) Math.log(i));
        System.out.print('\t');
        System.out.print(i);
        System.out.print('\t');
        System.out.print((int) (i * Math.log(i)));
        System.out.print('\t');
        System.out.print(i * i);
        System.out.print('\t');
        System.out.print(i * i *i);
        System.out.println();
    }
```

It prints differently in IntelliJ and Command Prompt. See the pictures below:

#### IJ

[image: IJ]

#### cmd

[image: cmd]

What can I do if I want to see the same results in IJ as it is in cmd?

Thanks!

Comment: Different tab-sizes (4 vs. 8 characters). Check IJ settings if it has a separate one for the console, or try setting the code-formatting one (which is 4 for most IDE-s) to see if that one applies to the console too.

Comment: What differences are there? Different numbers? Different layout?

Comment: @kometen different tab-width

Comment: I advise you to close this question. It is not related to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ's command window has a tab width of 4, while the command prompt has a tab width of 8.

You could re-configure IntelliJ to use a tab width of 8, but I wouldn't recommend it.

---

> What can I do if I want to see the same results in IJ as it is in cmd?

Don't use tabs in your output, use spaces. Best achieved using `printf`:

```
System.out.println("log n   n       n log n n^2     n^3");
for (long i = 2; i <= 2048; i *= 2) {
    System.out.printf("%-8d", (int) Math.log(i));
    System.out.printf("%-8d", i);
    System.out.printf("%-8d", (int) (i * Math.log(i)));
    System.out.printf("%-8d", i * i);
    System.out.print(i * i * i);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Better yet:

```
System.out.println("log n   n       n log n n^2     n^3");
for (long i = 2; i <= 2048; i *= 2) {
    System.out.printf("%-7d %-7d %-7d %-7d %d%n",
                      (int) Math.log(i),
                      i,
                      (int) (i * Math.log(i)),
                      i * i,
                      i * i * i);
}
```

The reason for `%-7d<space>` instead of `%-8d` is that it'll still leave a space between values in case the value takes up more than 7 characters. Sure it'll ruin the nice column layout, but it still allows easier reading of the values.

*Output (both IJ and CMD)*

```
log n   n       n log n n^2     n^3
0       2       1       4       8
1       4       5       16      64
2       8       16      64      512
2       16      44      256     4096
3       32      110     1024    32768
4       64      266     4096    262144
4       128     621     16384   2097152
5       256     1419    65536   16777216
6       512     3194    262144  134217728
6       1024    7097    1048576 1073741824
7       2048    15615   4194304 8589934592
```